# Associated Types in Swift

Tags: swift, swift2

What are associated types in swift programming language? What are they used for?

As per swift programming language book:

> When defining a protocol, **it is sometimes useful** to declare one or
>   more associated types as part of the protocol’s definition. An
>   associated type gives a placeholder name (or alias) to a type that is
>   used as part of the protocol. The actual type to use for that
>   associated type is not specified until the protocol is adopted.
>   Associated types are specified with the typealias keyword.

The above text is not very clear to me. It would help a lot if you can explain associated types with an example.

Also, why is it useful to declare an associated type as part of a protocol definition?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why don't associated types for protocols use generic type syntax in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554987/why-dont-associated-types-for-protocols-use-generic-type-syntax-in-swift)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have a protocol that defines methods and perhaps properties that an implementing type must provide. Some of those methods/properties use or return objects of a different type to the type implementing the protocol. So, for instance, if you have a protocol that defines certain types of collections of objects, you might define an associated type which defines the elements of the collection.

So let's say I want a protocol to define a `Stack`, but a Stack of what? It doesn't matter, I just use an associated type to act as a place holder.

```
protocol Stack
{
    // typealias Element - Swift 1
    associatedtype Element // Swift 2+
    func push(x: Element)
    func pop() -> Element?
}
```

In the above `Element` is the type of whatever objects are in the stack. When I implement the stack, I use `typealias` to specify the concrete type of the stack elements.

```
class StackOfInt: Stack
{
    typealias Element = Int // Not strictly necessary, can be inferred
    var ints: [Int] = []

    func push(x: Int)
    {
        ints.append(x)
    }

    func pop() -> Int?
    {
        var ret: Int?
        if ints.count > 0
        {
            ret = ints.last
            ints.removeLast()
        }
        return ret
    }
}
```

In the above, I have defined a class that implements `Stack` and says that, for this class, `Element` is actually `Int`. Frequently, though, people leave out the `typealias` because the concrete type of `Element` can be inferred from the method implementations. e.g. the compiler can look at the implementation of `push()` and realise from the type of the parameter that `Element == Int` in this case.

Comment: For more deep understand, please read the reference of great article: https://www.natashatherobot.com/swift-what-are-protocols-with-associated-types/

Answer (score 5):

An associated type gives a placeholder name to a type that’s used as part of the protocol. The actual type to use for that associated type isn’t specified until the protocol is adopted.

The class which adopts the protocol will decide the type of placeholder-name(Ex: MyType)

Example:

```
 protocol MyProAssociate {
    associatedtype MyType
    func sumOf(x: MyType, y: MyType) -> MyType
 }

 class MyCls1: MyProAssociate {

    typealias MyType = Int
    func sumOf(x: Int, y: Int) -> Int {
       return x + y
    }
 }

class MyCls2: MyProAssociate {

  typealias MyType = Float
  func sumOf(x: Float, y: Float) -> Float {
    return x + y
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bro, very simple and easy to understand