# Creating a factory for a protocol with associated type

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

New to Swift and trying to find nice ways of deciding which implementation of a protocol to use. Protocols with associated types don't seem to map onto generic interfaces in other languages at all. I thought something like the following would have worked.

```
protocol Foo {
    associatedtype Item

}

class FooOffline<T>: Foo {
    typealias Item = T

}

class FooOnline<T> : Foo {
    typealias Item = T
}

func makeFoo<T, F: Foo>() -> F where F.Item == T{
    return FooOnline<T>()
}
```

Am I going down the wrong path? Even if, could someone offer an explanation for why this wouldn't work?

Comment: Yes, this is the wrong path. You will generally find the right path by exploring your actual problem. What would `makeFoo()` do in your real (in front of you, right now) code that just calling `FooString()` wouldn't?

Comment: And you're right, PATs (protocols with associated types) are not generic interfaces. Figuring out what tool you really need depends on what problem you're really solving. Factories usually aren't the right answer.

Comment: [This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554987/why-dont-associated-types-for-protocols-use-generic-type-syntax-in-swift)

Comment: @RobNapier I'll update the example to more functional.

Comment: It did. I ended up using a type erasure solution to actually obtain a reference to an `AnyFoo`.