# Trying to create C# method that outputs an object of a generic type that's nested inside another generic type

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I'm currently working on writing a method that, for the sake of this problem, generates mazes.

Here's the (simplified) version of the classes involved:

```
public interface IAlgorithm<out MazeType> where MazeType : Maze
{
    MazeType GoGenerate();
}
```

```
public class AlgorithmBacktrack : IAlgorithm<Maze>
{
    public Maze GoGenerate()
    {
        //Do things
        return new Maze();
    }
}
```

```
public class Maze
{
}

public class MazeWithPath : Maze
{
}
```

What I'd like to do now is create helper to call this Algorithm:

```
public class MazeGenerator
{
    public static MAZETYPEGENERIC Generate<AlgorithmType>()
        where AlgorithmType : IAlgorithm<MAZETYPEGENERIC>, new()
    {
        var alg = new AlgorithmType();
        return alg.GoGenerate();
    }
}
```

The thing that I can't get to work though is the MAZETYPEGENERIC. Theoretically C# could know that whatever interface implementation of IAlgorithm I put in there would have the MAZETYPEGENERIC configured. However C# still want's me to add that as a Generic parameter to the method. E.g.:

```
public static MAZETYPEGENERIC Generate<AlgorithmType, MAZETYPEGENERIC>()
    where AlgorithmType : IAlgorithm<MAZETYPEGENERIC>, new()
    ...
```

This however would mean that the invocation of this call would also require this parameter. Even though it could theoretically be inferred from the AlgorithmType.

```
//Ideal way to call this method:
Maze m = MazeGenerator.Generate<AlgorithmBacktrack>();

//Actual way to call this after adding the additional generic parameter:
Maze m = MazeGenerator.Generate<AlgorithmBacktrack, Maze>();
```

I would love to see/hear if someone has an idea on how to accomplish option 1 (the ideal way of doing this).

Comment: Two generic parameters are inevitable. Unless it's enough to return predefined type, like e.g. `IMaze` (`public static IMaze Generate<AlgorithmType>()...`)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to accept an instance of `IAlgorithm<MAZETYPEGENERIC>`, and let type inference infer the type parameter `MAZETYPEGENERIC` . Now you wouldn't need the `AlgorithmType` type parameter

```
Maze m = MazeGenerator.Generate(new AlgorithmBacktrack());

...

public static MAZETYPEGENERIC Generate<MAZETYPEGENERIC>(IAlgorithm<MAZETYPEGENERIC> algorithm)
    where MAZETYPEGENERIC : Maze {
    return algorithm.GoGenerate();
}
```

You *would have* been able to access the type parameter of `IAlgorithm` if C# interfaces used associated types (like Swift), rather than generics. So it's not like this is completely impossible feature to have in a language. For a comparison see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554987/why-dont-associated-types-for-protocols-use-generic-type-syntax-in-swift).

Comment: Hmm the reason I creates the MazeGenerator class is to have an abstraction where you'd not have to instantiate the Algorithm class. (In the real application there's more classes. So if I would do it like this I could just as well call the Algorithm directly.

Comment: @Devedse Well, C#'s generics aren't strong enough unfortunately. You must have 2 type parameters if you want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If "instantiate the Algorithm class" is all you need, the closest I can get is probably by moving the call to `GoGenerate` method out of `Generate` method, like this:

```
static T Generate<T>() where T : IAlgorithm<Maze>, new()
{
    return new T();
}

Maze m = MazeGenerator.Generate<AlgorithmBacktrack>().GoGenerate();
// I made the algorithm class up
MazeWithPath m = MazeGenerator.Generate<AlgorithmBacktrack2>().GoGenerate();
```

Or if the type of local variable `m` is always `Maze`, you could also do something like:

```
static Maze Generate<T>() where T : IAlgorithm<Maze>, new()
{
    return new T().GoGenerate();
}
```

Also want to comment on

> Theoretically C# could know that whatever interface implementation of IAlgorithm I put in there

I hope C# would not (like it currently does). `T` in your case is [covariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-generic-modifier). If `T` is implementation of `IAlgorithm<MazeWithPath>`, both `Maze`, `MazeWithPath` and `object` are semantically correct for return type.

The compiler can't choose one without knowing the context of your code. And if it can, it *may* choose a wrong one for you:

```
// This is only correct when the compiler chooses MazeWithPath as return type
// It will become invalid if compiler chooses Maze or object
MazeWithPath m = Generate<AlgorithmBacktrack2>();
```

In saying that, making `Generate` method to take two generic parameters *might* make more sense IMO.