# How to handle multiple generic protocols in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I'm trying to use two generic protocols that relate to each other as:

```
protocol PersistableData {}

protocol DataStore: class {
    associatedtype DataType: PersistableData

    func save(data: DataType, with key: String)

    func retreive(from key: String) -> DataType?
}

protocol PersistentDataModel {
    // Swift infers that DataType: PersistableData as DataType == DataStoreType.DataType: PersistableData
    // Setting it explicitly makes the compiler fail
    associatedtype DataType
    associatedtype DataStoreType: DataStore where DataStoreType.DataType == DataType
}

extension String: PersistableData {}

protocol StringDataStore: DataStore {
    associatedtype DataType = String
}


class Test: PersistentDataModel {
    typealias DataType = String
    typealias DataStoreType = StringDataStore
}
```

However Xcode fails to compile saying that `Type 'Test' does not conform to protocol 'PersistentDataModel'` and suggesting that `Possibly intended match 'DataStoreType' (aka 'StringDataStore') does not conform to 'DataStore'` while `StringDataStore` is defined as conforming to `DataStore`

I've read a few good resources about generic protocols including [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24469913/how-to-create-generic-protocols-in-swift) and this [Medium post](https://medium.com/developermind/generics-in-swift-4-4f802cd6f53c), but I could not find where the issue is.

Comment: Why do you have `associatedtype DataStoreType: DataStore where DataStoreType.DataType == DataType`?

Comment: This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself) might help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happening because your `typealias` for `associatedtype` should have concretion, not abstraction.

Thus, for your case, `StringDataStore` should be a `class`, not `protocol`.

```
protocol PersistableData {}

protocol DataStore: class {
associatedtype DataType: PersistableData

    func save(data: DataType, with key: String)

    func retreive(from key: String) -> DataType?
}

protocol PersistentDataModel {
    // Swift infers that DataType: PersistableData as DataType == DataStoreType.DataType: PersistableData
    // Setting it explicitly makes the compiler fail
    associatedtype DataType
    associatedtype DataStoreType: DataStore where DataStoreType.DataType == DataType
}
extension String: PersistableData {}

class StringDataStore: DataStore {
    typealias DataType = String

    func save(data: String, with key: String) {
        //
    }

    func retreive(from key: String) -> String? {
        return nil
    }
}

class Test: PersistentDataModel {
    typealias DataType = String
    typealias DataStoreType = StringDataStore
}
```

However, you can keep using protocols and solve it by using additional generics conditions in your `Test` class:

```
class Test<T: StringDataStore>: PersistentDataModel where T.DataType == String {
    typealias DataStoreType = T
    typealias DataType = T.DataType
}
```

Using this you can tell to compiler that concrete type will be passed to `Test` somewhere else.

Like this:

```
class ConcreteStringDataStore: StringDataStore {
    func save(data: String, with key: String) {
        //
    }

    func retreive(from key: String) -> String? {
        return nil
    }
}

let test = Test<ConcreteStringDataStore>()
```