# generics in swift protocols

Tags: swift, protocols

I am trying to migrate the Visitor pattern from my (old) java code to swift. So far I have a generic FIFO (working fine).

```
protocol FiFo {
    associatedtype U
    func enqueue(_ : U)
    func dequeue() -> U
}
```

I also want to tell the instance of the FIFO only to accept an instance of a visitor that uses the same type for the generic as the instance of the FIFO.

```
protocol Visitor {
    associatedtype T
    func processValue(_ value : T)
}
protocol FiFo {
    associatedtype U
    func enqueue(_ : U)
    func dequeue() -> U
    func visit(_ visitor : Visitor<U>)
}
```

Here I am facing:

> Cannot specialize non-generic type 'Visitor'

Any hints? Thanks!

Comment: Generics and associated types are two different things.

Comment: Thanks for your answers - I would love to mark both helpful. And thanks for the general hint that there is a difference between generics vs associated types (in swift).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create generic protocols in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24469913/how-to-create-generic-protocols-in-swift)

Comment: @RTXGamer: Re your edit: The backticks are for `code`, not for general emphasis. “Visitor pattern” or ”fifo” is not code.

Comment: @pkamb: I've found that other question, but I wasn't  sure at all how to apply that solution to the problem of two protocols. The part when `where` comes in was not that clear to me in the other post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the `visit` method generic: Accept any visitor whose associated type `T` is the fifo's type `U`:

```
protocol FiFo {
    associatedtype U
    func enqueue(_ : U)
    func dequeue() -> U
    func visit<V: Visitor>(_ visitor : V) where V.T == U
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add a constraint to an associated type:

```swift
protocol Visitor {
    associatedtype T
    func processValue(_ value : T)
}

protocol FiFo {
    associatedtype U
    associatedtype V: Visitor where V.T == U
    func enqueue(_ : U)
    func dequeue() -> U
    func visit(_ visitor: V)
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I had not seen your answer appearing. Now I wonder if there is a difference between our suggestions or if they are equivalent.

Comment: @MartinR - No worries. Re differences b/w generic and associated type, it is the standard homogeneous vs heterogeneous issues: E.g., should there be more than one `FiFo` method that takes a `Visitor`, having multiple methods with `where V.T == U`, they don’t necessarily need to be the same type, whereas associated type can enforce that). If it really is only one generic method with `Visitor`, your generic pattern is more concise.